# How to create a map of vectors of vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

I'm trying to make a map containing vectors containing vectors but I am getting an error when trying to access an element.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int, vector<vector<string>>> m;
    m[0][0].push_back("hi");
    return 0;
}
```

You can try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/HytLmjQJV

The error I'm getting is in Visual Studio:

> Debug assertion failed.Program : Expression:vector subscript out of range.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly, please ***tell us*** the errors (copy-pasted into the question itself).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude edited my question. Hope it's better.

Answer (score 3):

m[0] is an empty vector in your code so you cannot access its first element (m[0][0]).
You need to create a vector inside, e.g.

```
m[0].push_back({});
m[0][0].push_back("hi");
```

Comment: FYI -- `m.insert({0, {{"hi"}}});` Also works.  If you wanted to add more than one string to the vector at key 0: `m.insert({0, {{"hi"},{"there"},{"everyone"}}});`

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" here is that you have 3 nested containers, so you need to add values to all of them to store your `"hi"` value.
When you do this `m[0][0].push_back("hi");` you are basically accessing the position `0` of each `vector` inside the `map`, but you didn't set any values in them, they are empty.

#### I will first break it down to better explain.

With nested containers, like `map<int, vector<vector<string>>>`, the easiest way to understand how they work is to break it down.

```
map<int, vector<vector<string>>> m;

vector<string> inner; // Inner vector
vector<vector<string>> outer; // Outer vector


inner.push_back("Hi"); // Inner vector value
outer.push_back(inner); // Outer vector value

    // Map holds pairs
m.insert(pair<int, vector<vector<string>>>(10, outer));

    // Accessing data
cout << m[10][0][0] << endl;
```

*Output*

```
> Hi
```

#### Simplifying

That said you can easily and more cleanly write something like this.

```
m.insert({20, {{"Hi2"}}});

    // Accessing data
cout << m[20][0][0] << endl << endl;
```

*Output*

```
> Hi2
```

Where the first set of curly braces, `{20, {...}}`,  is the pair that is inserted into the `map`. Think of it as the `map` only caring about a pair of an `int` and a `vector`.
Then you have that `vector`, outer curly braces `{{...}}`, knowing it holds another `vector`.
This `vector`, inner curly braces `{""}`, knows it holds strings.

Essentially with the curly braces we are doing the same as described above, creating separate values for each of the containers, a pair and two vectors.

#### Extending

Then you can easily scale it up with more data.

```
m.insert({25, {{"Hi2", "Hi3", "Hi4"}, {"By1", "By2"}}});

    // Accessing data
cout << m[25][0][0] << endl;
cout << m[25][0][1] << endl;
cout << m[25][0][2] << endl << endl;

cout << m[25][1][0] << endl;
cout << m[25][1][1] << endl;
```

*Output*

```
> Hi2 
> Hi3
> Hi4 
>
> By1
> By2
```

#### Note

You can check the project [here](https://repl.it/@Aandree05/MapVectorVectorString) to see it working.
Also in c++ a `map` doesn't have a `push_back()` but if you want something similar to it you can use `emplace()` and do something like this `m.emplace(20, outer)`, although it doesn't work with the shorter versions with the curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

While you are trying to add to this vector properly, you haven't added anything to your vector. You're attempting to grab something that isn't there.

You'll need to put something in that first vector.

```
m[0].pushback();
m[0][0].pushback("hi");
```

alternatively, you could create the vector that you're going keep inside that first vector, first.

```
vector<string> vec1;
vec1.pushback("hi");

m[0].pushback(vec1);
```